# Sometime Image will not load content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue with some legacy code.

When I test the code, I'm unable to replicate the problem reported by the customer.

The Issue
Sometimes the border will get the right size(Height,Width) But the displayed content is empty.(no image, just white background).
This issue occurs approximately once in every 10,000 attempts.

The current simplified code:

```
public SomeLegacyClass()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(@"\\SomeShare\Data\User\folder\image.jpg");
    list.Add(@"\\SomeShare\Data\User\folder\image2.jpg");
    list.Add(@"\\SomeShare\Data\User\folder\image3.jpg");

    this.FillGrid(list);
    this.Width = (int)System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    this.Height = (int)System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        foreach (var item in this.ImageGrid.Children)
        {
            var br = item as Border;
            if (br != null)
            {
                br.Height = (br.Child as FrameworkElement).ActualHeight;
                br.Width = (br.Child as FrameworkElement).ActualWidth;
            }
        }
    };
}

public void FillGrid(List<string> images)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.ImageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    this.ImageGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

    int columnCount = 0;
    int rowCount = 0;
    int count = images.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int randomIndex = rand.Next(0, images.Count);
        string path = images.ElementAt(randomIndex);
        images.Remove(path);
        Image image = new Image();

        BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
        imageSource.BeginInit();
        imageSource.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        imageSource.EndInit();

        image.Source = imageSource;

        if (rowCount == this.ImageGrid.RowDefinitions.Count)
        {
            this.ImageGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }

        var border = new Border() { BorderThickness = new Thickness(4), BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black };
        border.Child = image;
        border.Margin = new Thickness(6);
        Grid.SetRow(border, rowCount);
        Grid.SetColumn(border, columnCount);
        rowCount++;

        this.ImageGrid.Children.Add(border);

        if (rowCount == 3 && images.Count != 0)
        {
            this.ImageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            columnCount++;
            rowCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be causing it?

**Update:**
I was able to reproduce this issue(random).
What i found is that imageSource has PixelHeight and PixelWidth set to 1. I have not encountered any errors or exceptions.

**Update:**
Well, I can now simulate the problem quite reliably and have found out where the issue lies. It turns out that there is a memory issue. When the image is being decoded, it can fail due to "insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program". This exception doesn't raise any error directly, but it can be caught by the DecodeFailed event.

Comment: As a general hint, better use an ItemsControl with a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel. Declare the Border with Image child in the ItemTemplate, and assign the List of path strings to the ItemsSource property.

Comment: Have you considered network connectivity issue? since your images are loaded from `\\SomeShare....` - I doubt WPF has an in-built mechanism to retry fetching the image if it fails to load

Comment: Yes I have considered it and its possible that this is the issue and I dont realy know how to prevent it or how to prove it. I tried some tests with events like DownloadCompleted but this event is not raised with when stream is used.

Comment: You could open a FileStream from the path, and assign that to the StreamSource property of the BitmapImage. It should throw an exception when the file could not be read.

Comment: Never dealt with external images in WPF, only ever used images that were part of the application. So, because of lack of knowledge I would simply try to copy the image to a local space eg. `%TEMP%` and wrap the file.copy in a `for` loop to retry it x time if it failed and log exceptions

Comment: I have updated the Question. It seems that imageSource successfully loads the image without throwing any errors, but the PixelHeight and PixelWidth remain set to 1.